# Re-creating a method which is already in component inside a store js file in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This can be a simple question but since I'm in a learning curve of vuejs I'm struggling to achieve following task.

I have this method inside one of my vue component.

```
async loadSuggestedUsers() {
            if (!this.suggestionUrl) return false
            else this.isSearching = true;

            this.cancelPreviousRequest();

            await axios.get(`/${Helper.getLocale()}/dashboard/${this.suggestionUrl}`, {
                params: {
                    page: this.suggestedUsersData.page,
                    per_page: this.suggestedUsersData.perPage,
                    search_text: this.searchText,
                    nationality: this.selectedNationalities
                },
                cancelToken: this.requestToken.token
            }).then(({data}) => {
                collect(data.data).each((user) => {
                    if (!this.suggestedUsers.some(obj => obj.id === user.id)) {
                        this.suggestedUsers.push(user)
                    } else if (
                        user.project_specific_job_title_id &&
                        !this.suggestedUsers.some(obj => obj.project_specific_job_title_id === user.project_specific_job_title_id)
                    ) {
                        this.suggestedUsers.push(user)
                    }
                })
                this.suggestedUsersData.perPage = data.per_page
                this.suggestedUsersData.total = data.total

                this.isSearching = false
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error instanceof axios.Cancel) return false;
            });
        },
```

but now, Instead of directly calling this method from the component I'm trying to access this by using `store` .

Under my store, I have a `js` file called, `TestStore.JS`

My questions are,

How can I re-create above method in my TestStore.JS and how call that recreated method in my component...

Comment: that method seems to rely on a LOT of component data (all those `this.xxxxx`) so, it seems that function is component specific - why would you want to put that in your "store"

Comment: by the way ... since `loadSuggestedUsers` is `async` ... using `.then` makes no sense ... use `await` for just the axios.get without the .then, and the code will be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a state for this function in your store and pass its reference to it in the created lifecycle of the component.